# How to insert using rest API created using SPRING BOOT DATA REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

Hi I m noob at rest and I try to learn how to use it in Spring Boot.

I used Spring Boot Data Rest to generate a Rest service and since I don't have all the basics on rest I wonder how to use a POST to insert into my database knowing that I have a get answer that is as below

http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "mNG_USERs": [
        {
            "us_cextusr": "1234e",
            "us_nomusr": "test",
            "us_prnusr": "test",
            "us_pwdusr": "123456",
            "us_datdeb": "2018-03-03",
            "us_datfin": "2018-03-03",
            "us_nbrerr": 1,
            "us_datcre": "2018-03-03",
            "us_datmaj": "2018-03-03",
            "us_etatusr": null,
            "us_typusr": null,
            "us_lastprg": null,
            "us_nivacc": null,
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs/1"
                },
                "mNG_USER": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs/1"
                },
                "us_langue": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs/1/us_langue"
                },
                "us_lastuser": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs/1/us_lastuser"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs{?page,size,sort}",
        "templated": true
    },
    "profile": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/mNG_USERs"
    }
},
"page": {
    "size": 20,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "number": 0
}
}
```

I m using postman to generate request I know that I should use a POST request But how to write it I don't know

Comment: You should look at the REST basics before you go and try to do something like this.  You can get shown code but it's not going to benefit you at all unless you understand what it is you're being shown.

Comment: https://spring.io/understanding/REST what can I get from this please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work and research

First using curl under postman is simple we have to choose the adequate method for the purpose in my case post to create (since I will use put to update), Secondly Spring Boot Data Rest generated API is well documented you can discover it by Posting to your RestApi host.

to build my post I used Post : http://localhost:8080/mNG_USERs and in postman there is a body section I selected raw and JSON format

```
{
  "us_cextusr" : "123158E",
  "us_nomusr" : "test",
  "us_prnusr" : "loli",
  "us_pwdusr" : "123456",
  "us_datdeb" : "2018-03-03",
  "us_datfin" : "2018-03-03",
  "us_nbrerr" : 1,
  "us_datcre" : "2018-03-03",
  "us_datmaj" : "2018-03-03",
  "us_etatusr" : null,
  "us_typusr" : null,
  "us_lastprg" : null,
  "us_nivacc" : null  
}
```